# Удаление уникальных элементов из массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Как удалить из массива только уникальные элементы, а те которые повторяются оставить в том же количестве и порядке?
Например, `arr = [1,3,3,4,5,6,4,1]` на выходе должно стать `[1,3,3,4,4,1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать через `filter()`, `lastIndexOf()` и `indexOf()`:

```js
var arr = [1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 1];

var res = arr.filter(function(number, index, arr) {
  return (!(arr.lastIndexOf(number) == index) || !(arr.indexOf(number) == index)) && true;
});

console.log(res);
```

Вариант, который вам дали чуть ранее, скорее всего тоже будет верно работать, но предоставленный мной выглядит наиболее лаконично и красиво, как по мне. В нем мы за счет двух функций проверяем, является ли индекс очередного элемента одновременно индексом и первого и последнего в массиве элемента с таким значением (это и есть проверка на уникальность), и если это верно, то за счет логических операций возвращаем в `filter()` ложь, за счет чего отфильтровываем уникальный элемент.

Comment: Во-первых, "красиво" - это очень субъективно, так что говорить "мой вариант наиболее красивый" попросту некорректно. Во-вторых, за этой "лаконичностью" скрывается сложность выражения, из-за которой его сложнее читать и сложнее написать без ошибок. В-третьих, за всем этим "красиво" скрываются проблемы с производительностью. Да, на массиве из 8 элементов всё хорошо, однако на массиве из миллиона уникальных чисел мой вариант отрабатывает за 45мс, а ваш - за 580000мс (второй раз запускать уже не стал).

Comment: @Regent, если вы внимательнее прочитаете мой ответ, то в нем прямо говорится о том, что мнение о красоте субъективно ("как по мне"). Что касается сложности кода, то на этот раз я уже замечу, что это все субъективно. Ну а что касается скорости, то можете попробовать дополнить свой ответ кодом теста и упоминанием этого момента. Кому это будет критично, тот сможет самостоятельно и проверить результаты вашего теста, и выбрать подходящий ему вариант, включая автора вопроса.

Comment: Хорошо, что есть несколько вариантов. Есть над чем подумать. Как начинающему, первый вариант более понятен, хотя благодаря второму, наконец разобрался в методах filter, lastIndexOf\IndexOf.

Comment: @VyacheslavLamash я кстати сам потестировал на скорость, код товарища работает примерно 55-60мс, мой - 380мс, то есть разница есть, но не на какие-то чудовищные порядки, а "всего" в 6-7 раз, на миллионной выборке.

Comment: Дело в вашей формулировке сравнивания ответы. Вот эти фразы "скорее всего тоже будет верно работать, но" и "предоставленный мной выглядит наиболее лаконично и красиво"  звучат ровно как "вот тот ответ так себе, а мой - куда лучше". И добавление "как по мне" эту ситуацию не исправляет. Возможно, вы этого не подразумевали, но получилось именно так. Это во-первых. Во-вторых, если у вас [этот fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qerxstd4/) работает за 380мс, то это что-то очень странно. У меня (Opera 44.0.2510.857, процессор i5-6500) этот код работает ровно обозначенное время.

Comment: @Regent 1) слова "скорее всего" говорят лишь о том, что я не несу ответственности за ваш код, не тестировал его и не проверял, все остальное - ваши собственные субъективные оценки, замешанные на том, что вы автор собственно этого кода; 2) ваш код тестирования неверен, у пользователя явно не от 1 до 1000000 будут числа в массиве, а 0-9, по крайней мере на основании его примера это выглядит именно так. Мой код для тестирования тут: https://pastebin.com/SiTjppu1, проверял в интерпретаторе самого RU.SO

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko Ваш код - О(n^2), код Regent-a - O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Для этого можно подсчитать количество вхождений каждого элемента, после чего в результирующий массив добавлять только те элементы, для которых подсчитанное количество больше единицы:

```js
var arr = [1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 1];
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    var number = arr[i];
    if (data[number] == undefined)
    {
        data[number] = 0;
    }
    data[number]++;
}
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    var number = arr[i];
    if (data[number] > 1)
    {
        result.push(number);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Написал аналогичный код https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/825987/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0/825992#825992 с `О(n)`, но люди почему-то упорно принимают ответы с `О(n^2)`.

Comment: @Igor возможно, алгоритм за квадрат легче воспринимается новичками...