# Удалить уникальный элемент из массива

Tags: javascript

Всем привет такая проблемма, не могу понять где ошибка в моём коде.

Задача заключается в том, что нужно вернуть массив, состоящий только из неуникальных элементов данного массива. Мой код работает но почему-то не доконца правильно.

```js
function nonUniqueElements(array) {

    var new_array = [];
//    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
            if (array[i] !== array[j]) {
                array.splice(array[i], 1);
                return array;
            }

    }

    return array;
}

console.log(nonUniqueElements([1, 2, 3, 1, 3]));
console.log(nonUniqueElements([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(nonUniqueElements([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]));
console.log(nonUniqueElements([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8]));
```

Если посмотреть в консоль то 1 и 3 -й варианты получаются правильно, но остальные нет.

Comment: Потому что Вы вызываете `return` во внутреннем цикле.

Comment: @Igor Хорошо а где бы его стоило вызывать ?

Comment: `return` прерывает выполнение функции. Выходит, вы делаете один проход. Просто уберите внутренний, внешний итак вернёт, что надо.

Comment: @Dmig тогда уж придется и логику чинить :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё немного сложнее чем кажется, вы допустили много ошибок, во первых у вас удаляется один элемент, после которого цикл завершается возвратом массива, во вторых вы удаляете элемент с неправильной позиции используя значение `array[i]`, вместо `i`, также при удалении элемента из массива, нужно учитывать, что индексы сдвигаются, поэтому необходимо вернуть индекс на один назад.

Вот решение, если текущий элемент единственный, то он удаляется:

```js
function nonUniqueElements(array) {

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       if(array.filter(item => item == array[i]).length == 1){
          array.splice(i, 1);
          --i;
       }
    }

    return array;
}

console.log(nonUniqueElements([1, 2, 3, 1, 3]));
console.log(nonUniqueElements([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(nonUniqueElements([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]));
console.log(nonUniqueElements([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8]));
```

Comment: Спасибо за доступное объяснение. Мне единственный момент не понятен, что значит item и почему именно item? (Просто относительно недавно начал учить JS)

Comment: item => item == array[i] это стрелочная функция, аналог function(item){ return  item == array[i]; }, т.е. item это название аргумента функции и он может быть любым.

Comment: Спасибо, хоть и не всё до конца понятно. Буду учится.

Comment: @Komdosh Ваш код - О(n^2), мой код - O(n).

Comment: @Igor, согласен, и я вам поставил балл, но мой ответ был построен на основе вопроса, я попытался мысли автора реализовать

Answer (score 4):

```js
function nonUniqueElements(array) {
  var counts = {};
  array.forEach(item => counts[item]? counts[item]++ : counts[item] = 1);
  return array.filter(item => counts[item] > 1);
}

console.log(nonUniqueElements([1, 2, 3, 1, 3]));
console.log(nonUniqueElements([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(nonUniqueElements([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]));
console.log(nonUniqueElements([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8]));
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function nonUniqueElements(array) {
  return array.filter((el, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(el) != arr.lastIndexOf(el));
}

console.log(nonUniqueElements([1, 2, 3, 1, 3]));
console.log(nonUniqueElements([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(nonUniqueElements([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]));
console.log(nonUniqueElements([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8]));
```